# FluentAssertions 6 ObjectGraph compare Enum to String

Tags: c#, enums, fluent-assertions

With FluentAssertions 6 it seems you can longer verify if in a object graph if an Enum is equivalent to a string. Source: https://fluentassertions.com/upgradingtov6

```
enum MyEnum {
   A,
   B
}

class Source {
   MyEnum Enum { get;set;}
}

class Expectation {
   string Enum { get;set;}
}

var source = new Source() { Enum = MyEnum.A };
var expectation = new Expectation() {Enum = "A"};

//With V6 this assertion will fail but in V5 it will pass
expectation.Should().BeEquivalentTo(source, options => options.ComparingEnumsByName());
```

How can I assert the objects above with FluentAssertions? The behaviour I want is for the assertions to be made on the ToString representation of the enum.

As I side note, I get different behaviour when I swap the `expectation` with `source`. Shouldn't they be equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a more relaxed [equivalency step](https://fluentassertions.com/extensibility/#equivalency-assertion-step-by-step) to handle string/enum comparisons.

```cs
class RelaxedEnumEquivalencyStep : IEquivalencyStep
{
    public EquivalencyResult Handle(Comparands comparands, IEquivalencyValidationContext context, IEquivalencyValidator nestedValidator)
    {
        if (comparands.Subject is string subject && comparands.Expectation?.GetType().IsEnum == true)
        {
            AssertionScope.Current
                .ForCondition(subject == comparands.Expectation.ToString())
                .FailWith(() =>
                {
                    decimal? subjectsUnderlyingValue = ExtractDecimal(comparands.Subject);
                    decimal? expectationsUnderlyingValue = ExtractDecimal(comparands.Expectation);

                    string subjectsName = GetDisplayNameForEnumComparison(comparands.Subject, subjectsUnderlyingValue);
                    string expectationName = GetDisplayNameForEnumComparison(comparands.Expectation, expectationsUnderlyingValue);
                    return new FailReason(
                            $"Expected {{context:string}} to be equivalent to {expectationName}{{reason}}, but found {subjectsName}.");
                });

            return EquivalencyResult.AssertionCompleted;
        }

        if (comparands.Subject?.GetType().IsEnum == true && comparands.Expectation is string expectation)
        {
            AssertionScope.Current
                .ForCondition(comparands.Subject.ToString() == expectation)
                .FailWith(() =>
                {
                    decimal? subjectsUnderlyingValue = ExtractDecimal(comparands.Subject);
                    decimal? expectationsUnderlyingValue = ExtractDecimal(comparands.Expectation);

                    string subjectsName = GetDisplayNameForEnumComparison(comparands.Subject, subjectsUnderlyingValue);
                    string expectationName = GetDisplayNameForEnumComparison(comparands.Expectation, expectationsUnderlyingValue);
                    return new FailReason(
                            $"Expected {{context:enum}} to be equivalent to {expectationName}{{reason}}, but found {subjectsName}.");
                });

            return EquivalencyResult.AssertionCompleted;
        }

        return EquivalencyResult.ContinueWithNext;
    }

    private static string GetDisplayNameForEnumComparison(object o, decimal? v)
    {
        if (o is null)
        {
            return "<null>";
        }

        if (v is null)
        {
            return '\"' + o.ToString() + '\"';
        }

        string typePart = o.GetType().Name;
        string namePart = o.ToString().Replace(", ", "|", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        string valuePart = v.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return $"{typePart}.{namePart} {{{{value: {valuePart}}}}}";
    }

    private static decimal? ExtractDecimal(object o)
    {
        return o?.GetType().IsEnum == true ? Convert.ToDecimal(o, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : null;
    }
}
```

If it's just for a single test

```cs
var source = new Source() { Enum = MyEnum.A };
var expectation = new Expectation() { Enum = "A" };

expectation.Should().BeEquivalentTo(source, options => options.Using(new RelaxedEnumEquivalencyStep()));

source.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectation, options => options.Using(new RelaxedEnumEquivalencyStep()));
```

Or if you want this globally you can set this using `AssertionOptions.AssertEquivalencyUsing`.

- For MSTest put it in [`AssemblyInitialize`](https://www.meziantou.net/mstest-v2-test-lifecycle-attributes.htm#initialize-cleanup-b).
- For Xunit, see the [documentation](https://fluentassertions.com/tips/#xunitnet) or use [this Module Initializer example](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/1323#issuecomment-1020438420).

```cs
AssertionOptions.AssertEquivalencyUsing(e => e.Using(new RelaxedEnumEquivalencyStep()));

var source = new Source() { Enum = MyEnum.A };
var expectation = new Expectation() { Enum = "A" };

expectation.Should().BeEquivalentTo(source);
source.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectation);
```

For completeness here are examples of the failure message when `MyEnum` and `string` do not match.

```
Expected property root.Enum to be equivalent to "B", but found MyEnum.A {value: 0}.
Expected property source.Enum to be <null>, but found MyEnum.B {value: 1}.
Expected property root.Enum to be equivalent to MyEnum.A {value: 0}, but found "B".
Expected property expectation.Enum to be equivalent to MyEnum.B {value: 1}, but found <null>.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your expectation defines the `Enum` property as being a string, and the options you provide are used to instruct FA how the members of the expectation should be compared to the subject. So in this case, `ComparingEnumsByName` doesn't do anything since the property involved is a `string`. What you could do instead is to use an anonymous type as the expectation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the issue is that I can’t control the source and expected.

Comment: You cannot change the unit test so it uses an anonymous type in your expectation? That doesn't affect the production code at all.

Comment: I use AutoFixture to create the expectation which is then used for a WireMock setup.

Comment: I see what you mean now - yes I could do an extra conversion from my AutoFixture to an anonymous type before the assertion.